# Beautiful Soup : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn Beautiful Soup. Am using below URL for learning purpose.
https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/intro-to-beautiful-soup

When I try to run the code I get below error.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'what_is_beautiful_soup_in_python-Google_Search.html'
```

Both the Python module and HTML file are saved in the same folder.
Name of HTML file = `what_is_beautiful_soup_in_python-Google_Search`
Can anyone please help me resolving this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("what_is_beautiful_soup_in_python-Google_Search.html"), features="lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: So what's your code?

Comment: Hi, am really sorry, forgot to add my code earlier, now post updated, thanks a lot for the help. Have a nice day ahead. :)

Answer (score 1):

Double check the name of the html file and references to the html file. 
Then check the extension and make sure it is an html document.
Consider changing the name of the html filename to something simpler like 'index.html' (this helps with fat thumbs.)